# How can I remove the drop down listbox "editor" from the basic settings of the form were user edits his profile?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

How can I remove the drop down listbox "Editor (optional)" from the basic settings of the form were user edits his profile? 
I don't need it.

[image]

Here is the code of the com_users/views/profile/tmpl/edit.php view file.

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  com_users
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 * @since       1.6
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive');
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation');
JHtml::_('behavior.noframes');
//load user_profile plugin language
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang->load( 'plg_user_profile', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR );
?>
<div class="profile-edit<?php echo $this->pageclass_sfx?>">
<?php if ($this->params->get('show_page_heading')) : ?>
    <h1><?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_heading')); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>

<form id="member-profile" action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&task=profile.save'); ?>" method="post" class="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php foreach ($this->form->getFieldsets() as $group => $fieldset):// Iterate through the form fieldsets and display each one.?>
    <?php $fields = $this->form->getFieldset($group);?>

    <?php if (count($fields)):?>
    <fieldset>
        <?php if (isset($fieldset->label)):// If the fieldset has a label set, display it as the legend.?>
        <legend><?php echo JText::_($fieldset->label); ?></legend>
        <?php endif;?>
        <dl>
        <?php foreach ($fields as $field):// Iterate through the fields in the set and display them.?>
            <?php if ($field->hidden):// If the field is hidden, just display the input.?>
                <?php echo $field->input;?>
            <?php else:?>
                <dt>
                    <?php echo $field->label; ?>
                    <?php if (!$field->required && $field->type!='Spacer' && $field->name!='jform[username]'): ?>
                        <span class="optional"><?php echo JText::_('COM_USERS_OPTIONAL'); ?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dt>
                <dd><?php echo $field->input; ?></dd>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
        </dl>
    </fieldset>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach;?>

        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="validate"><span><?php echo JText::_('JSUBMIT'); ?></span></button>
            <?php echo JText::_('COM_USERS_OR'); ?>
            <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('component/users/profile.html'); ?>" title="<?php echo JText::_('JCANCEL'); ?>"><?php echo JText::_('JCANCEL'); ?></a>

            <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_users" />
            <input type="hidden" name="task" value="profile.save" />
            <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: are you referring to the section where users can choose which editor they use, language etc?

Comment: I am sorry I rephrased the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to disable only the **Editor** parameter. You can however remove the entire **Basic Settings**, by following these steps:

1. In the Joomla backend, go to **User Manager**
2. Go to **Options**
3. Set the **Frontend User Parameters** to **hide**

Remove only the **Editor** parameter, the only method I can think of without hacking core code is to use CSS to hide it.